# Whither dispatch_once in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3, libdispatch

Okay, so I found out about the new [Swifty Dispatch API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801370/957768) in Xcode 8. I'm having fun using `DispatchQueue.main.async`, and I've been browsing around the `Dispatch` module in Xcode to find all the new APIs.

But I also use `dispatch_once` to make sure that things like singleton creation and one-time setup don't get executed more than once (even in a multithreaded environment)... and `dispatch_once` is nowhere to be found in the new Dispatch module?

```
static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
func whatDoYouHear() {
    print("All of this has happened before, and all of it will happen again.")
    dispatch_once(&token) {
        print("Except this part.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since Swift 1.x, Swift has been using `dispatch_once` [behind the scenes](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2daa1400cf79a2965eb07034b48ef7fae02459fd/lib/IRGen/SwiftTargetInfo.cpp) to perform thread-safe lazy initialization of global variables and static properties.

So the `static var` above was already using `dispatch_once`, which makes it sort of weird (and possibly problematic to use it again as a token for another `dispatch_once`. In fact there's really no safe way to use `dispatch_once` without this kind of recursion, so they got rid of it. Instead, just use the language features built on it:

```
// global constant: SomeClass initializer gets called lazily, only on first use
let foo = SomeClass()

// global var, same thing happens here
// even though the "initializer" is an immediately invoked closure
var bar: SomeClass = {
    let b = SomeClass()
    b.someProperty = "whatever"
    b.doSomeStuff()
    return b
}()

// ditto for static properties in classes/structures/enums
class MyClass {
    static let singleton = MyClass()
    init() {
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

So that's all great if you've been using `dispatch_once` for one-time *initialization* that results in some value -- you can just make that value the global variable or static property you're initializing.

But what if you're using `dispatch_once` to do work that doesn't necessarily have a result? You can still do that with a global variable or static property: just make that variable's type `Void`:

```
let justAOneTimeThing: () = {
    print("Not coming back here.")
}()
```

And if accessing a global variable or static property to perform one-time work just doesn't feel right to you -- say, you want your clients to call an "initialize me" function before they work with your library -- just wrap that access in a function:

```
func doTheOneTimeThing() {
    justAOneTimeThing
}
```

See the [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) for more.

Comment: Considering that Singleton "is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object", wouldn't be nice to add `private` to the class' constructors? Notice that if have a variable in this class you could have multiple instances holding a different value for this variable. Once the constructor is `private`, only the `static let singleton` line would be able initialize it.

Comment: What if I've to use an instance variable in the `dispatch_once` block?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : there's actually a lot more to that comment than meets the eye. Why not post it as a separate question?

Comment: @rickster I've posted in on apple developers fourm after searching on SO. I'll post the solution as soon as I get it. Here is the post : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69433?sr=stream

Answer (score 22):

While the "lazy var" pattern allows me to stop caring about dispatch tokens and is generally more convenient than `dispatch_once()` was, I don't like what it looks like at the call site:

```
_ = doSomethingOnce
```

I would expect this statement to look more like a function call (since it implies action), but it doesn't look so at all. Also, having to write `_ =` to explicitly discard the result is annoying.

There is a better way:

```
lazy var doSomethingOnce: () -> Void = {
  print("executed once")
  return {}
}()
```

Which makes the following possible:

```
doSomethingOnce()
```

This might be less efficient (since it calls an empty closure instead of just discarding a `Void`), but improved clarity is totally worth it for me.

Comment: same minor caveat as simply using `Void`: if someone writes `doSomethingOnce = {}` before the first call, it will not call it even once.

Comment: Please advise if there is a way to remove the compiler error that is generated at the site of declaration of the "doSomethinOnce" if the code it contains can throw and exception. "lazy var doSomethingOnce: () throws -> Void"

Comment: @user2196409 The errors thrown from the function can be handled at the call site by marking the call with the `try` keyword, just as with normal throwing functions (I checked this in Swift 4.2).

Answer (score 17):

The other answers here and around the interwebs are pretty great, but I feel this little tidbit should also be mentioned:

The great thing about `dispatch_once` was how optimized it was, essentially nixing the code after the first run in a way that I hardly understand, but am reasonably assured that would be that much faster than setting and checking a (real) global token.

While the token thing could be reasonably implemented in Swift, having to declare yet another stored boolean isn't all that great. Not to mention thread-unsafe. As the [doc](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) says, you should use a "lazily initialized global." Yeah, but why clutter up the global scope, right?

Until somebody convinces me of a better method, I tend to declare my do-once closure inside the scope I'll be using it in, or reasonably close thereto, as follows:

```
private lazy var foo: Void = {
    // Do this once
}()
```

Basically I'm saying that "When I read this, `foo` should be the result of running this block." It behaves the exact same way as a global `let` constant would, just in the right scope. And prettier. Then I'd call it wherever I'd like, by reading it into something that'll never be used otherwise. I like Swift's `_` for that. Like so:

```
_ = foo
```

This really cool quirk has actually been around a while, but hasn't seen much love. It basically leaves the variable alone at runtime, as an uncalled closure, until something wants to see its `Void` result. On read, it calls the closure, throws it away and keeps its result in `foo`. `Void` uses practically nothing memory-wise, so subsequent reads (i.e. `_ = foo`) do nothing on the CPU. (Don't quote me on that, somebody please check up on the assembly to be sure!) Have as many as you like, and Swift basically quits caring about it after the first run! Lose that old `dispatch_once_t`, and keep a lot of your code as pretty as when you first opened it Christmas day!

My one issue is that you can set `foo` to something else before its first read, and then your code will *never* be called! Hence the global `let` constant, which prevents that. Thing is, constants in class scope don't play well with `self`, so no playing with instance variables... But seriously, when do you set *anything* to `Void` anyway??

That, and you'd need to specify the return type as `Void` or `()`, else it'll still complain about `self`. Who'da thunk?

And `lazy` is just to make the variable as lazy as it should be, so Swift doesn't run it straight off on `init()`.

Pretty snazzy, so long as you remember not to write to it! :P

Comment: There is a subtle difference between your and @rickster approaches. Your _"lazily initialized locals"_  once action is done once **per instance**, while _"lazily initialized globals"_ once action is done once **per type**. [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/evgeniyd/82fcbd15c4727e040d9b58380888110c)

Answer (score 8):

## Example for "dispatch_once" in Swift 3.0

#### Step 1 : Just Replace below code with your Singleton.swift (Singleton class)

```
// Singleton Class
class Singleton: NSObject { 
var strSample = NSString()

static let sharedInstance:Singleton = {
    let instance = Singleton ()
    return instance
} ()

// MARK: Init
 override init() {
    print("My Class Initialized")
    // initialized with variable or property
    strSample = "My String"
}
}
```

[Singleton Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ezJ.png)

#### Step 2 : Call Singleton from ViewController.swift

```
// ViewController.swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let mySingleton = Singleton.sharedInstance
        print(mySingleton.strSample)

        mySingleton.strSample = "New String"
        
        print(mySingleton.strSample)
        
        let mySingleton1 = Singleton.sharedInstance
        print(mySingleton1.strSample)

    }
```

[ViewController Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3fiF.png)

#### Output like this

```
My Class Initialized
My String
New String
New String
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is only dispatched once? why wouldn't a race between 2 threads accessing the sharedInstance collide? Also, being a "static" it is initialized at some unknown time - whether or not we need it. The nice thing about dispatch_once, is that I could control if/when it is executed.

Answer (score 6):

**Compiles under Xcode 8 GA Swift 3**

The recommended and elegant way to create a dispatch_once singleton class instance:

```
final class TheRoot {
static let shared = TheRoot()
var appState : AppState = .normal
...
```

To use it:

```
if TheRoot.shared.appState == .normal {
...
}
```

What do these lines do?

final - so the class cannot be overridden, extended, it also makes the code somewhat faster to run, less indirections.

static let shared = TheRoot() - This line does lazy init, and it only runs once.

This solution is thread safe.

Comment: Can you please explain how come this is "lazy init"? my experience with static vars in other languages, is that the compiler inserts the initialization code for them at some arbitrary time, near loading. Never lazy, as far as I know. Where is the definition for that in swift?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Migration Guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/):

> The free function dispatch_once is no longer available in Swift. In
>   Swift, you can use lazily initialized globals or static properties and
>   get the same thread-safety and called-once guarantees as dispatch_once
>   provided.

Example:

```
  let myGlobal = { … global contains initialization in a call to a closure … }()

  // using myGlobal will invoke the initialization code only the first time it is used.
  _ = myGlobal
```

Answer (score -3):

Thread-safe dispatch_once:

```
private lazy var foo: Void = {
    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

    // Do this once
}()
```

Comment: the existing lazy mechanism is thread-safe already (in the sense that it executes at most once). This extra bit of "thread safety" does not help, and may hurt.

Comment: @polytopia For the following variable `private lazy var foo: Void = { print("hello") }()` this code will print "hello" multiple times (reproduced on simulator only): `for _ in 0 ... 1000 { DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { _ = self.foo } } }`