# dispatch_once after the Swift 3 GCD API changes

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

What is the new syntax for `dispatch_once` in Swift after the changes made in language version 3? The old version was as follows.

```
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
func test() {
    dispatch_once(&token) {
    }
}
```

These [are the changes to libdispatch](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0088-libdispatch-for-swift3.md) that were made.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Whither dispatch_once in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37801407/957768)

Comment: Based on the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311178/1648724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983813/1648724 , I created a CocoaPod to do this: [`pod 'SwiftDispatchOnce', '~> 1.0'`](https://github.com/JRG-Developer/SwiftDispatchOnce) Cheers. :]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

From the [doc](https://swift.org/migration-guide/):

> Dispatch
>   The free function dispatch_once is no longer available in
>   Swift. In Swift, you can use lazily initialized globals or static
>   properties and get the same thread-safety and called-once guarantees
>   as dispatch_once provided. Example:

```
let myGlobal: () = { … global contains initialization in a call to a closure … }()
_ = myGlobal  // using myGlobal will invoke the initialization code only the first time it is used.
```

Comment: It's not as if you didn't know that Swift would be changing rapidly and you would have to correct a lot of broken code between versions of Swift.

Comment: the biggest pain is the 3rd party pods which are not always Swift3 compatible.

Comment: That's the technical debt you accrue when introducing third party dependencies, @Tinkerbell. I love Swift but am extra cautious bringing in external dependencies that use it for this very reason.

Comment: `dispatch_once` was clear. This, unfortunately, is ugly and confusing..

Answer (score 109):

While using lazy initialized globals can make sense for some one time initialization, it doesn't make sense for other types.  It makes a lot of sense to use lazy initialized globals for things like singletons, it doesn't make a lot of sense for things like guarding a swizzle setup.

Here is a Swift 3 style implementation of dispatch_once:

```
public extension DispatchQueue {

    private static var _onceTracker = [String]()

    /**
     Executes a block of code, associated with a unique token, only once.  The code is thread safe and will
     only execute the code once even in the presence of multithreaded calls.

     - parameter token: A unique reverse DNS style name such as com.vectorform.<name> or a GUID
     - parameter block: Block to execute once
     */
    public class func once(token: String, block:@noescape(Void)->Void) {
        objc_sync_enter(self); defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

        if _onceTracker.contains(token) {
            return
        }

        _onceTracker.append(token)
        block()
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
DispatchQueue.once(token: "com.vectorform.test") {
    print( "Do This Once!" )
}
```

or using a UUID

```
private let _onceToken = NSUUID().uuidString

DispatchQueue.once(token: _onceToken) {
    print( "Do This Once!" )
}
```

As we are currently in a time of transition from swift 2 to 3, here is an example swift 2 implementation:

```
public class Dispatch
{
    private static var _onceTokenTracker = [String]()

    /**
     Executes a block of code, associated with a unique token, only once.  The code is thread safe and will
     only execute the code once even in the presence of multithreaded calls.

     - parameter token: A unique reverse DNS style name such as com.vectorform.<name> or a GUID
     - parameter block: Block to execute once
     */
    public class func once(token token: String, @noescape block:dispatch_block_t) {
        objc_sync_enter(self); defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

        if _onceTokenTracker.contains(token) {
            return
        }

        _onceTokenTracker.append(token)
        block()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I was exactly getting trapped in a swizzle setup. I hope the swift team address this use case.

Comment: You absolutely should not be using `objc_sync_enter` and `objc_sync_exit` anymore.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: For performance you should use a set instead of an array for the _onceTrackers. This improves the time complexity from O(N) to O(1).

Comment: That could be an improvement if the list was large.  The assumption is the list of items being tacked will be small.

Comment: So you write a reusable class assuming it won't be reused that much :-) If it requires no additional effort to lower the time complexity from O(N) to O(1) you should always do it IMHO.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) Why not use Set<String>? 2) Looks like we can use `os_unfair_lock` instead of `objc_sync_enter `

Comment: Swift 4 / 5 version somewhere?

Answer (score 69):

Expanding on Tod Cunningham's answer above, I've added another method which makes the token automatically from file, function, and line.

```
public extension DispatchQueue {
    private static var _onceTracker = [String]()
    
    public class func once(
        file: String = #file,
        function: String = #function,
        line: Int = #line,
        block: () -> Void
    ) {
        let token = "\(file):\(function):\(line)"
        once(token: token, block: block)
    }
    
    /**
     Executes a block of code, associated with a unique token, only once.  The code is thread safe and will
     only execute the code once even in the presence of multithreaded calls.
     
     - parameter token: A unique reverse DNS style name such as com.vectorform.<name> or a GUID
     - parameter block: Block to execute once
     */
    public class func once(
        token: String,
        block: () -> Void
    ) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
        
        guard !_onceTracker.contains(token) else { return }
        
        _onceTracker.append(token)
        block()
    }
}
```

So it can be simpler to call:

```
DispatchQueue.once {
    setupUI()
}
```

and you can still specify a token if you wish:

```
DispatchQueue.once(token: "com.hostname.project") {
    setupUI()
}
```

I suppose you could get a collision if you have the same file in two modules. Too bad there isn't `#module`

Comment: this sheds some more light on whats going on. Thanks.

Comment: Linking to code above: https://gitlab.com/zakkhoyt/DispatchOnceExample/raw/master/DispatchOnceExample/DispatchQueue+Once.swift

Comment: Really helped  Thanx

Comment: but if I understand it, your code will executed only once, even if the class is removed and recreated, right? it's different from the original dispatch_once, if I remember it right...
isn't?

Comment: @yonivav Yes you are correct. To get around this you could also pass in the memory address of the object along with file, line, etc... Make the address part of the token.

Answer (score 21):

Edit

### @Frizlab's answer - this solution is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. An alternative should be used if this is crucial

Simple solution is

```
lazy var dispatchOnce : Void  = { // or anyName I choose

    self.title = "Hello Lazy Guy"

    return
}()
```

used like

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    _ = dispatchOnce
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all, because a lazy var declaration cannot be made inline with regular code, it has to be in a struct or class definition. That means the contents of the dispatchOnce cannot capture surrounding scope of an instance. For example if you declare a closure that has not run yet, you cannot then declare the struct inside that closure and have the lazy var's contents be another closure that captures vars from the surrounding closure...

Comment: Downvoted because this code has definitely **not** the same semantics as dispatch_once. dispatch_once ensures the code is run exactly once, **whichever thread you call it from**. Lazy vars have undefined behavior in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: in this solution init block is going to call twice in some cases

Answer (score 11):

You can declare a top-level variable function like this:

```
private var doOnce: ()->() = {
    /* do some work only once per instance */
    return {}
}()
```

then call this anywhere:

```
doOnce()
```

Comment: Lazy vars are scoped to the class, so this absolutely will not act like dispatch_once. It will execute once per instance of the underlying class. Either move it outside the class [ private var doOnce: ()->() = { } ] or mark it static [ static private var doOnce: ()->() = { } ]

Comment: Absolutely correct! Thanks. In most cases you'll need once action per instance.

Comment: This is a really great solution! Elegant, short, and clear

Answer (score 10):

You can still use it if you add a bridging header:

```
typedef dispatch_once_t mxcl_dispatch_once_t;
void mxcl_dispatch_once(mxcl_dispatch_once_t *predicate, dispatch_block_t block);
```

Then in a `.m` somewhere:

```
void mxcl_dispatch_once(mxcl_dispatch_once_t *predicate, dispatch_block_t block) {
    dispatch_once(predicate, block);
}
```

You should now be able to use `mxcl_dispatch_once` from Swift.

Mostly you should use what Apple suggest instead, but I had some legitimate uses where I needed to `dispatch_once` with a single token in two functions and there is not covered by what Apple provide instead.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3: For those who likes reusable classes (or structures):

```
public final class /* struct */ DispatchOnce {
   private var lock: OSSpinLock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT
   private var isInitialized = false
   public /* mutating */ func perform(block: (Void) -> Void) {
      OSSpinLockLock(&lock)
      if !isInitialized {
         block()
         isInitialized = true
      }
      OSSpinLockUnlock(&lock)
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   private let /* var */ setUpOnce = DispatchOnce()

   override func viewWillAppear() {
      super.viewWillAppear()
      setUpOnce.perform {
         // Do some work here
         // ...
      }
   }

}
```

---

**Update** (28 April 2017): `OSSpinLock` replaced with `os_unfair_lock` due deprecation warnings in macOS SDK 10.12.

```
public final class /* struct */ DispatchOnce {
   private var lock = os_unfair_lock()
   private var isInitialized = false
   public /* mutating */ func perform(block: (Void) -> Void) {
      os_unfair_lock_lock(&lock)
      if !isInitialized {
         block()
         isInitialized = true
      }
      os_unfair_lock_unlock(&lock)
   }
}
```

Comment: I get a message that OSSSpinLock is deprecated in iOS 10.0

Comment: Thanks! Example code updated. `OSSpinLock` replaced with `os_unfair_lock`. BTW: Here is a good WWDC video about `Concurrent Programming`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/

Answer (score 3):

Swift provides the easiest way to achieve that by declaring lazy initialized property, it is guaranteed to be run only once. All we want to do is just read the property at needed moment.

```
 lazy var executeOnce: Void = {
      print("")
  }()

  for 0...100 {
    _ = executeOnce  // will run only once we access it for first time (in our first loop's iteration)
  }
```

In that example "" will be printed only once, regardless of how many times we tried to call it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I improve above answers get result:

```
import Foundation
extension DispatchQueue {
    private static var _onceTracker = [AnyHashable]()

    ///only excute once in same file&&func&&line
    public class func onceInLocation(file: String = #file,
                           function: String = #function,
                           line: Int = #line,
                           block: () -> Void) {
        let token = "\(file):\(function):\(line)"
        once(token: token, block: block)
    }

    ///only excute once in same Variable
    public class func onceInVariable(variable:NSObject, block: () -> Void){
        once(token: variable.rawPointer, block: block)
    }
    /**
     Executes a block of code, associated with a unique token, only once.  The code is thread safe and will
     only execute the code once even in the presence of multithreaded calls.

     - parameter token: A unique reverse DNS style name such as com.vectorform.<name> or a GUID
     - parameter block: Block to execute once
     */
    public class func once(token: AnyHashable,block: () -> Void) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

        guard !_onceTracker.contains(token) else { return }

        _onceTracker.append(token)
        block()
    }

}

extension NSObject {
    public var rawPointer:UnsafeMutableRawPointer? {
        get {
            Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add example about how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

  // dispatch once
   class StaticOnceTest {
    
    static let test2 = {
        print("Test " + $0 + " \($1)")
    }("mediaHSL", 5)
    
    lazy var closure: () = {
        test(entryPoint: $0, videos: $1)
    }("see all" , 4)
    
    private func test(entryPoint: String, videos: Int) {
        print("Test " + entryPoint + " \(videos)")
    }
    }

print("Test-1")
let a = StaticOnceTest()
a.closure
a.closure
a.closure
a.closure
StaticOnceTest.test2
StaticOnceTest.test2
StaticOnceTest.test2
StaticOnceTest.test2
```

OUTPUT:

```
Test-1
Test see all 4
Test mediaHSL 5
```

You can use a **lazy var closure** and **execute** it immediately with (#arguments_if_needed) so that it will call only one time. You can call any instance function inside of the closure [**advantage**].

You can pass multiple arguments based on need. You can capture those arguments when the class has been initialised and use them.

Another option: You can use a **static let closure** and it will execute only one time but you cannot call any instance func inside that static let clsoure. [**disadvantage**]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

`dispatch_once` is still available in `libswiftFoundation.dylib` standard library which is embedded to any swift app so you can access to exported symbols dynamically, get the function's symbol pointer, cast and call:

```swift
import Darwin

typealias DispatchOnce = @convention(c) (
    _ predicate: UnsafePointer<UInt>?,
    _ block: () -> Void
) -> Void

func dispatchOnce(_ predicate: UnsafePointer<UInt>?, _ block: () -> Void) {
    let RTLD_DEFAULT = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: -2)
    
    if let sym = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "dispatch_once") {
        let f = unsafeBitCast(sym, to: DispatchOnce.self)
        f(predicate, block)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("Symbol not found")
    }
}
```

Example:

```swift
var token: UInt = 0

for i in 0...10 {
    print("iteration: \(i)")
    
    dispatchOnce(&token) {
      print("This is printed only on the first call")
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```sh
iteration: 0
This is printed only on the first call
iteration: 1
iteration: 2
iteration: 3
iteration: 4
iteration: 5
iteration: 6
iteration: 7
iteration: 8
iteration: 9
iteration: 10
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the class constant approach if you are using Swift 1.2 or above and the nested struct approach if you need to support earlier versions.
An exploration of the Singleton pattern in Swift. All approaches below support lazy initialization and thread safety.
dispatch_once approach is not worked in Swift 3.0

Approach A: Class constant

```
class SingletonA {

    static let sharedInstance = SingletonA()

    init() {
        println("AAA");
    }

}
```

Approach B: Nested struct

```
class SingletonB {

    class var sharedInstance: SingletonB {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: SingletonB = SingletonB()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

}
```

Approach C: dispatch_once

```
class SingletonC {

    class var sharedInstance: SingletonC {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SingletonC? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SingletonC()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asked about a solution for Swift 3.