# How to prevent extension to be exported to Swift header for Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I made this simple extension in Swift:

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    func asyncAfter(delay: TimeInterval, block: @escaping ()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: block)
    }
}
```

In Project-Swift.h header it reports error at this line:

```
@interface OS_dispatch_queue (SWIFT_EXTENSION(...))
- (void)asyncAfterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay block:(void (^ _Nonnull)(void))block;
@end
```

> Error is: Cannot find interface declaration for 'OS_dispatch_queue'

Is there a way to prevent extension being exported for Objective-C? Or is there a way to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer per say, but i encounter the same problem using the public extension DispatchQueue on: 
[dispatch_once after the Swift 3 GCD API changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-after-the-swift-3-gcd-api-changes/39983813#39983813)

So on my case using the solution from Vlad helped me avoiding this constant problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570198/1672521

Answer (score -3):

You can use `@objc` before the `func` or `method` to prevent being exported for objective-C like below.

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    @objc func asyncAfter(delay: TimeInterval, block: @escaping ()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: block)
    }
}
```

Comment: its '@noobjc' for preventing ... but it doesn't solve the problem because class 'DispatchQueue' is still exported to 'OS_dispatch_queue' which is unknown to Objective-C  and it still fails.