# How to prevent a UIDatePicker from being initialized multiple times

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UIDatePicker and based on my code I believe that each time a cell in a table view is selected the date picker is re-created or something similar to the date picker being re-created occurs. I have looked into something called a singleton but I am confused about they work because I am new to swift. Would a singleton prevent this problem? If so how would I implement one into my code. If not how do I prevent this issue from occurring? Here is my code for the function I use to call createDatePicker and the function createDatePicker:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

func createDatePicker(indexPath: IndexPath, textField: UITextField){

    //Tool Bar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //Bar Button Item
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)

    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    textField.inputView = datePicker



}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if(indexPath.row != 0){

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2

        cell.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.textField.delegate = self

        if(indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3){

            createDatePicker(indexPath: indexPath, textField: cell.textField)

        }

        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()


        if(indexPath.row == 1){

            cell.textField.placeholder = "Event Title"

        } else if(indexPath.row == 2){

            cell.textField.placeholder = "Start Time"

        } else if(indexPath.row == 3){


            cell.textField.placeholder = "End Time"

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Why is it a problem that a separate date picker is created for every cell? There is no need for you to create the picker inside `didSelect` method. It can be a property on the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is the right way (like with `DateFormatters`, that are heavy too but often reused):

```
class GlobalDatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    static let shared = GlobalDatePicker()
}
```

You'll use a single date picker instance in your code.

You can also use a `private init()`, to prevent callers from creating instances without going through the singleton.

```
class GlobalDatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    static let shared = GlobalDatePicker()
    private init() {}
    // Your methods that modify the picker here...
}
```

But you can also make a `static variable` in your controller:

```
static var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    return picker
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make your `datePicker` static like:

```
static let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
```

Then you don't need to go through singleton. But if you want singleton, you can go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311178/3687801) where you can find multiple ways of having singleton behavior in **Swift-3**.