# How to call function on time? Also How to Call only once time in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, timer

How to call function on time? Also How to Call only once time in swift 3?

i need to call one function one time only, so how can possible to call function only one time like after 3 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to program a delay in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031137/how-to-program-a-delay-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start timer:

```
  var timerUpdateArray:Timer!
  func callTimer(){
        self.timerUpdateArray = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, 
        target: self, selector: #selector(yourFunc), 
        userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }
```

For stop timer:

```
 self.timerUpdateArray.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
   yourFunction() // call your functin here
}
```

You can also use `DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter` if you don't want to perform your task on main thread!

And refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-in-swift-3) to manage it one time only!

Comment: its call multiple times, repeating calling function after every 3 second

Comment: you should refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
private let _onceToken = NSUUID().uuidString

DispatchQueue.once(token: _onceToken) {
     print( "Do This Once!" )
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
         yourFunction() // call your functin here
     }
}
```

It will execute your method only once and delay your method for 3 seconds.