# Swift function can be called only once

Tags: swift, function, static, lazy-loading, grand-central-dispatch

What is the simplest way to write a piece of code that can be executed only once?

I know a way but has a problem.

first, I write a Boolean variable that has negative value but can be set to positive and cannot change after that

```
 var hasTheFunctionCalled : Bool = false {
   didSet{
       hasTheFunctionCalled = true
   }
}
```

and then write the function and the code inside it:

```
func theFunction(){
   if !hasTheFunctionCalled{
      //do the thing
   }
   hasTheFunctionCalled = true
 }
```

but the problem is that the variable can be changed from somewhere else in the scope and this solution doesn't really look so simple and concrete.

Comment: where are you calling the function?

Comment: I want to declare it inside a class but will call out from outside. I want to try Julien's answer. It seems brilliant.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A simple solution is to take advantage of `lazy` variables in the following way:

```
// Declare your "once-only" closure like this
private lazy var myFunction: Void = {
    // Do something once
}()

...

// Then to execute it, just call
_ = myFunction
```

This ensures that the code inside the `myFunction` closure is only executed the first time that the program runs `_ = myFunction`

---

Edit: Another approach is to use so called "dispatch once tokens". This comes from Objective-C and was available in Swift until Swift 3. It is still possible to make it work, however you will need to add a little bit of custom code. You can find more information on this post -> [dispatch_once after the Swift 3 GCD API changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-after-the-swift-3-gcd-api-changes#38311178)

---

Edit2: Should be `_ = myFunction` and not `_ = myFunction()`, as JohnMontgomery pointed out.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but with this solution, you can't decide when the function is called though.

Comment: Yes, you can. The function will be only be executed when the line `_ = myFunction()` is called.

Comment: ok, thank you. I though it would be a little bit like a static function

Comment: I edited my post to add another approach, maybe you will prefer it. If my post helped you please upvote :)

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `_ = myFunction` without the `()`?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes I think you're correct. Thanks for pointing this out, I will edit my post.

Comment: Interesting. Found that ReactiveSwift uses exactly this approach for their `UIScheduler`: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/3c448a4432e17771cc2924328ccd1fd076f48a16/Sources/Scheduler.swift#L95

Answer (score 8):

You might use a static bool inside a struct nested into the function itself doing so:

```
func theFunction(){
    struct Holder { static var called = false }

    if !Holder.called {
        Holder.called = true
        //do the thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One possible technique is to put the code into the initializer of a static type property, which is guaranteed to be lazily initialized only once (even when accessed across multiple threads simultaneously):

```
func theFunction() {
    struct Once {
        static let once = Once()
        init() {
            print("This should be executed only once during the lifetime of the program")
        }
    }
    _ = Once.once
}
```

(Compare [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID14) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference.)

Example:

```
print("Call #1")
theFunction()
print("Call #2")
theFunction()
print("Done")
```

Output:

```
Call #1
This should be executed only once during the lifetime of the program
Call #2
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use UserDefaults, and the knowledge that the default UserDefault Bool is false:

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ExecuteOnce") {
    func()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ExecuteOnce")
}
```

This code will execute exactly once.

Answer (score 2):

You can do smth like:

```
class Once {

  var already: Bool = false

  func run(@noescape block: () -> Void) {
    guard !already else { return }

    block()
    already = true
  }
}
```

and than use it like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let once = Once()

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    once.run {
      cameraMan.setup()
    }
  }
}
```

ref: https://dev.to/onmyway133/how-to-run-action-once-in-swift-3k7o

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing inside your method : you may check if the end result has already been accomplished :

e.g. if you instantiate a class, check if it is different from nil