# dispatch_once in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
    func willRunOnceCoach() -> () {
    //        struct TokenContainer {
    //            static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
    //        }
    //
    //        dispatch_once(&TokenContainer.token) {
    //            print("This is printed only on the first call")
    //            self.createCochMark()
    //        }
    //    }
```

Above is the dispatch_once code block and i want to convert it to swift 3. How can i do that??
    AS of now i  m getting the following error:
    "dispatch_once is unavailable in swift "
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: referring the link i dont understand and i m new to swift and objective c

Comment: Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-after-the-swift-3-gcd-api-changes

Comment: DispatchQueue.once do i need to add any thing in pod file?