# How do you write a Swift completion block that can only be called once?

Tags: ios, swift, property-wrapper

Let's say I have a Swift class that stores a completion block, and does a few asynchronous tasks.

I want that block to be called by whichever of the tasks finishes first, but only that one - I don't want it to be called again when the second task finishes.

How can I implement this in a clean way?

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Hey @PGDev I included the code in the answer below (answered my own question :))

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need this to be thread safe, you can solve this problem with a fairly straightforward `@propertyWrapper`.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct ReadableOnce<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T? {
        mutating get {
            defer { self._value = nil }
            return self._value
        }
        set {
            self._value = newValue
        }
    }
    private var _value: T? = nil
}
```

Mark the completion block `var` with `@ReadableOnce`, and it will be destroyed after the first time it's value is read.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    @ReadableOnce private var completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?

    init(completion: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)) {
        self.completion = completion
    }

    public func doSomething() {
        // These could all be invoked from different places, like your separate tasks' asynchronous callbacks
        self.completion?(error) // This triggers the callback, then the property wrapper sets it to nil.
        self.completion?(error) // This does nothing
        self.completion?(error) // This does nothing
    }
}
```

I wrote up [more of a detailed discussion of this here](https://andrewking.ca/2020/02/using-a-swift-propertywrapper-to-ensure-a-closure-is-only-called-once/) but the key thing to be aware of is that **reading the value sets it to nil, even if you don't invoke the closure!** This might be surprising to someone who isn't familiar with the clever property wrapper you've written.

Comment: I would just be careful with this. In your case "does nothing" might be fine, but in general you probably want to log, fail a test, etc. when the later calls occur. Otherwise you might end up with strange tasks going on in the background that you never notice and which eat up memory/battery.

Comment: Totally agree - this may not be appropriate for all cases (or any depending on how you feel about this :D)

Comment: I don't quite see why the property wrapper is needed. There is already a standard built-in way of expressing onceness; why not just use it?

Comment: @matt Oh is there a better way I've missed? Thats's certainly possible - what are you referring to?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886994/dispatch-once-after-the-swift-3-gcd-api-changes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801407/whither-dispatch-once-in-swift-3 and others.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a standard expression of onceness. Unfortunately the standard Objective-C is unavailable in Swift (GCD `dispatch_once`), but the standard Swift technique works fine, namely a property with a lazy define-and-call initializer.

Exactly how you do this depends on the level at which you want onceness to be enforced. In this example it's at the level of the class instance:

```
class MyClass {
    // private part
    private let completion : (() -> ())
    private lazy var once : Void = {
        self.completion()
    }()
    private func doCompletionOnce() {
        _ = self.once
    }
    // public-facing part
    init(completion:@escaping () -> ()) {
        self.completion = completion
    }
    func doCompletion() {
        self.doCompletionOnce()
    }
}
```

And here we'll test it:

```
    let c = MyClass() {
        print("howdy")
    }
    c.doCompletion() // howdy
    c.doCompletion()
    let cc = MyClass() {
        print("howdy2")
    }
    cc.doCompletion() // howdy2
    cc.doCompletion()
```

If you promote the private stuff to the level of the class (using a static `once` property), the completion can be performed only once in the lifetime of the entire program.

Comment: Interesting technique. 