# 'dispatch_once_t' is unavailable in Swift: Use lazily initialized globals instead

Tags: swift, swift3

I am having trouble with `dispatch_once_t` when migrating to Swift 3.

According to [Apple's migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/):

> The free function dispatch_once is no longer available in Swift. In
>   Swift, you can use lazily initialized globals or static properties and
>   get the same thread-safety and called-once guarantees as dispatch_once
>   provided. Example:
>
> `let myGlobal = { … global contains initialization in a call to a closure … }()`
>
> `_ = myGlobal  // using myGlobal will invoke the initialization code only the first time it is used.`

So I wanted to migrate this code. So it was before migration:

```
class var sharedInstance: CarsConfigurator
{
    struct Static {
        static var instance: CarsConfigurator?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = CarsConfigurator()
    }

    return Static.instance!
}
```

After the migration, following the Apple's guidelines (manual migration), the code looks like this:

```
class var sharedInstance: CarsConfigurator
{
    struct Static {
        static var instance: CarsConfigurator?
        static var token = {0}()
    }

    _ = Static.token

    return Static.instance!
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error when accessing `return Static.instance!`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I see from this error that the `instance` member is `nil`, but why is it? Is it something wrong with my migration?

Comment: `dispatch_once` is removed in `Swift 3`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801408/5654848) answer on how to do things `once` instead.

Answer (score 23):

That code was overly verbose even though it was valid in Swift 2. In Swift 3, Apple forces you to use lazy initialization through closure:

```
class CarsConfigurator {
    static let sharedInstance: CarsConfigurator = { CarsConfigurator() }()
}
```