# dispatch_once_t alternative in swift

Tags: swift

Already Tried these:

['dispatch_once_t' is unavailable in Swift: Use lazily initialized globals instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516822/dispatch-once-t-is-unavailable-in-swift-use-lazily-initialized-globals-instea)

[Whither dispatch_once in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801407/whither-dispatch-once-in-swift-3)

Here is my code:
[image]

```
class var sharedInstance:Model{
        struct Static{
            static var instance:Model?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token){
            Static.instance = Model()
        }
        return Static.instance!

    }
```

Please suggest me alternative method for dispatch_once_t..I dont know swift, I code C/C++/Obj.C, please give me swift code to fix above problem

Comment: Alternative for `dispatch_once()` or rather a good way to make singleton (commonly named `sharedInstance` in Objective-C) ? That's a different question. For singleton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift ? Mimicing exactly another language and not adapt it to your current one is not recommended.

Comment: @Larme, thanks for your suggestions. Please give me swift version of code to fix above error...please answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In swift singleton can be written as,

```
class Model: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Model()
}
```

then use `Model.sharedInstance`. you dont need dispatch once like in objective c.

source https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: please change my code and what can be my updated code ?

Comment: Check now. Just add this only instead of your code in that class.

Comment: thanks a lots. This fixed problem and working great.