# Is there a way to add a one shot in swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’m wondering if there is a way to put a one shot in swift programming? If your familiar with PLC ladder logic you will know what I mean by a one shot.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Provide an example, what do you mean by one shot, otherwise most swift programmer will be unable to answer this question.

Comment: You've had two out of three questions closed, please read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article before asking another, and I strongly suggest that you put some effort into finding an answer before asking here. For example, you could have tried to find what the equivalent of a "one shot" is in Swift, and that probably would have led you to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with a specific function within Xcode that will achieve this however you can perform a sequential logic that depends on a variables state. Where bool1 is responsible for starting the sequence, bool2 is the latch/reset and var1 is the variable you wish to modify (or represents a section of code you only want performed once.)

```
var bool1 = false
var bool2 = false
var var1 = ""

if (bool1 == true && bool2 == true)
{
    var1 = "run code"
    bool2 = false
}
```

hope this helps?

Comment: Yes!!! This definitely provides a means for what I’m trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you meant `(bool1 == true && bool2 == true)` (double equal sign to check for equality)

Comment: I don’t believe this would be reliable or thread safe. It sounds to me like the OP is looking for `dispatch_once`.

Comment: hey Matt. I think this sounds like a viable solution but it sounds like this is something that can only be run once and never again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801407/whither-dispatch-once-in-swift-3 is that correct? I don't know if you are aware of what a one shot is but basically its a reusable "pulse" that activates and runs, then shuts itself off immediately after.