# How are updates to var arrays handled in Swift memory (confused about CoW)

Tags: arrays, swift, memory, memory-leaks, pass-by-reference

I have this function to do a quick select partition when sorting numbers in descending order. The function refers to `arr` defined outside its scope (partition is a nested func in another func).

My question was, since Arrays in Swift are value types, when I am doing swaps is a new copy created each time? Or is the same memory overwritten?

Would it be better to instead define the function as `partition(start: Int, end: Int, arr: inout [(Int, Int)])`, so arr can be passed by reference?

Follow-up question, what happens when we do `arr.append((4, 8))`? Will that create a new copy in memory?

```
func quickSelect(nums: [Int], k: Int) -> [Int] {

    // ... some logic 

    var arr = [(Int, Int)]() // nums frequencies eg: [(1, 2), (3, 5), (2, 8)]
    func partition(start: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
        var swap = start 

        for i in start..<end {
            if arr[i].1 > arr[end].1 {
                (arr[i], arr[swap]) = (arr[swap], arr[i]) // arr copied on write?
                swap += 1
            }
        }
        (arr[end], arr[swap]) = (arr[swap], arr[end]) // arr copied on write?
        return swap
    }

    // ... some logic 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copies won't be created *every* time you swap.

You seem to misunderstand what copy-on-write means in this context. We say that Swift arrays are copy-on-write, not because *every* time we write to it, a copy gets created.

Copy-on-write means "copy on ***write***", as opposed to "copy whenever the struct is copied". You might have misunderstood it as "***copy*** on write", as opposed to "keep using the same storage on write". It wouldn't be called an "optimisation" if it worked that way :)

Consider `var foo = bar` where `foo` and `bar` are arrays. The contents of `bar` are not copied to `foo`, because there is no *writes*. `foo` and `bar` share the same internal buffer, until either `bar` or `foo` got written to, at which point a copy will be created.

See also the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array#Modifying-Copies-of-Arrays) for `Array`:

> Arrays, like all variable-size collections in the standard library,
> use copy-on-write optimization. Multiple copies of an array share the
> same storage until you modify one of the copies. When that happens,
> the array being modified replaces its storage with a uniquely owned
> copy of itself, which is then modified in place. Optimizations are
> sometimes applied that can reduce the amount of copying.
>
> This means that if an array is sharing storage with other copies, the
> first mutating operation on that array incurs the cost of copying the
> array. An array that is the sole owner of its storage can perform
> mutating operations in place.

If like in your code, there is only one array variable, then no copies are needed. All the writes can be written to the same array's internal buffer. The array works like any other struct - it's the same principle as assigning a struct's property 1000 times will not make 1000 copies of that struct.

```
var s = SomeStruct()
for _ in 0..<1000 {
    s.property = ... // this won't copy s 1000 times
}
```

If you assigned `arr` to another variable first, before calling `partition`, then one copy will be created on the first swap, and no more copies after that.

As for calling [`append`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/append(_:)-1ytnt), the array might need to grow its [`capacity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/capacity) to append new elements. If `count == capacity`, then new memory needs to be allocated. This *might* involve relocating the array's contents, which you might count as "copying":

> When an array needs to reallocate storage before appending or its storage is shared with another copy, appending is O(n), where n is the length of the array.

Comment: A follow-up question, won't a copy of `arr` get created each time `partition` is called? In my experiment, the original `arr` does get updated (without using `inout`). But I am not sure how that happens for a value type. Does it work because `partition` is a function inside another function where  `arr` is defined? So it kind of works like a function in class updating its property?

Comment: So this is my point of confusion "difference between value types and reference types shows up if you start ... passing it to functions". I am passing arr to the partition function from the outer function. So won't partition receive a copy? How are the updates I make inside the partition function to arr reflected outside it (in the outer func that calls partition)?

Comment: I won't have the same confusion if `arr` was a reference type as `partition` would update the same reference that its outer scope has for arr. And then it makes sense to me that the updates made in `partition` are reflected in the outer scope.

Comment: @Parth Ah I see. No you are not “passing `arr` to `partition`. `partition` only takes 2 int parameters, none of its parameters is an array. And okay, so `partition` is nested in another function. I wasn’t aware of that. That just means the compiler has to secretly make a new parameter for the array, but that is an implementation detail. It *probably* does that by passing the array byref, but it might also do other things. At the language level, this will behave the same as if the array is a global variable.

Comment: @Parth it seems like your question is no longer just about arrays anymore, but value types in general. Please do not turn this into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).

Comment: @Parth If you really want, see how this works with a simpler example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/63ErTWEh3). When unoptimised, an extra argument is passed into `rsi`, with `mov  rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 16]`, which is clearly a reference. When optimisations are turned on, the compiler seems to have inlined everything, for this example anyway.

Comment: I will take a look at the link. My question was trying to ask that, but I worded it slightly poorly. Which I realized after reading your answer. I will ask a new question if the link you gave does not help.

Comment: @Parth So you are actually asking why there are no copies made when structs are captured. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71024264/5133585) is probably related. While that is about capturing in a closure, capturing in a nested function works much the same way.

Comment: Yes, this helps. Believe it or not, I read a similar example of closures with capture lists getting a copy elsewhere today! But I was not sure if func did the same. Looks like funcs by default act like closures without a capture list. And if I were to have an explicit `arr` parameter, then it would act like closure with a capture list. In which case I would need `inout` to get the reference to arr.