# Is it absolutely the case that Swift >will not< deep copy a large array, when one "guard let" the array?

Tags: ios, dictionary, reference, swift5, deep-copy

```
typealias Stuff = [[String]] // typically zillions of items
var stuff: [String: Stuff] = [:] // tens of these
```

When I deep copy† a `Stuff`,

```
spare: Stuff = original{
    let line = $0.map{ $0 }
    return line
}
```

it takes 1/2 sec on a new phone, so of course to avoid.

Now say I am working with a `Stuff`, like this `calculations(on: "Cats")`, strictly reading from `stuff["Cats"]`

```
///Strictly reading from Stuff
func calculations(on: String) {
  guard stuff[on] != nil else { return }
  .. = stuff[on]!.blah.blah
  .. = stuff[on]!.blah.blah
  ..
  .. dozens and dozens of reads from stuff[on]!
}
```

Of course it is much tidier if you

```
///Strictly reading from Stuff
func calculations(on: String) {
  guard let p = stuff[on] else { return }
  .. = p.blah.blah
  .. = p.blah.blah
  ..
  .. dozens and dozens of reads from p
}
```

If I do that,

- is it indeed ***not*** making a deep copy of `stuff["Cats"]` ?
- Is that truly reliable, and it will absolutely never do so?

As a related question, I believe, but I'm not sure,

that this would be how you check if indeed `p` is not a deep copy of `stuff["Cats"]` ->

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &p[0][0]) {
    print("p is at \($0)")
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &stuff["Cats"][0][0]) {
    print("whereas stuff["Cats"][0][0] is at \($0)")
}
```

Looks right?

---

† *As an aside, I really don't know if that is the best way to deep copy a 2D string array in Swift.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is guaranteed that no copies of the array storage are made. [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) has copy-on-write behaviour:

> Arrays, like all variable-size collections in the standard library, use copy-on-write optimization. Multiple copies of an array share the same storage until you modify one of the copies.
>
> [...]
>
> This means that if an array is sharing storage with other copies, the first mutating operation on that array incurs the cost of copying the array. An array that is the sole owner of its storage can perform mutating operations in place.

Though `let p = stuff[on]` copies the value of `stuff[on]` to `p`, the value of the `Array` struct is small - only 8 bytes on my machine (see `MemoryLayout<[[String]]>.size`).

The 8-byte struct value includes a pointer to some storage location for the array, and `p` and `stuff[on]` would be pointing to the same storage location, as the documentation says. From the standard library source, this would be an instance of the class [`__ContiguousArrayStorageBase`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/21fd18f802ce8ae61a1ff14f4dd9d686b1df52aa/stdlib/public/core/SwiftNativeNSArray.swift#L511).

The array storage will only be copied if you modify `stuff[on]` by e.g. adding another `[String]` to it. `p` and `stuff[on]` would now point to different storage locations. But even then, the *inner* arrays will still share storage, since you didn't modify the inner arrays.

Related: [How are updates to var arrays handled in Swift memory (confused about CoW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349445/how-are-updates-to-var-arrays-handled-in-swift-memory-confused-about-cow)

---

As for comparing the pointers, your code is comparing the locations of the elements in the inner array. As I said above, the outer array's storage could be copied even when the inner arrays are not, and vice versa, so you might want to compare `&stuff["Cats"][0]` and `&p["Cats"][0]` too.

Comment: @Fattie What is "apple cart"?

Comment: sorry *"upset the apple cart"* is an archaic figure of speech, simply meaning "mess things up".  To rephrase more clearly: to ask you for further confirmation, when I use `let p = stuff[on]` is there a danger of that disturbing the copy-on-write  behavior?  When I use `let p = stuff[on]` can I still safely assume that all you have explained, still applies?  TY !

Comment: @Fattie Yes. If you don't modify `stuff[on]` when `p` is in scope, there will be no copies. To add a bit more detail, when you modify a CoW collection, [`isKnownUniquelyReferenced`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/isknownuniquelyreferenced(_:)-98zpp) is called to check if there is only one strong reference to the class instance that acts as the storage. If there are more than one reference, then a copy of that storage is made.

Comment: facinating - you would certainly have to be careful if using multiple threads.  so in your example if I `let p = stuff[on]` there are then two (2) strong references.  say I change something (in one or indeed the other). Something checks `isKnownUniquelyReferenced`, the result is greater than one (it's two) and hence a copy is made. great stuff!

Comment: thanks again @Sweeper .  Purely FYI you may enjoy my current or follow-on question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220006