# Is it perfectly correct that this computed property will work like a "pointer" in current Swift?

Tags: dictionary, pass-by-reference, swift5, computed-properties

Have a data source singleton with

```
class hugestuff ..{

   var dataSources: [String: ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays] ..

   var currentThing: String

}
```

`ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays` is indeed a `struct`. A typical use might be enormous tables of values to display in a grid on a screen. Each `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays` - that is to say each entry in the `.dataSources` dictionary - could be a different screen, say.

```
struct ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays {
   var rawUnsorted: [[String]]
   var liveSorted: [[String]]
   var swapValues: [[String]]
}
```

So throughout the app, you're accessing

```
  cell.data = hugestuff.dataSources[currentThing].unsortedRows[3489412]
```

and so on.

And indeed sometimes changing things ...

```
  hugestuff.dataSources[currentThing].searchRows =
       hugestuff.dataSources[currentThing].unsortedRows.filter{blah}
```

This is all fantastic but ***purely as sugar*** it would be more convenient and sturdy if

```
  cell.data = hugestuff.hot.unsortedRows[3489412]

  hugestuff.hot.searchRows = hugestuff.hot.unsortedRows.filter{blah}
```

Well now, I believe that to achieve that, if you do this

```
var hot: ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays {
    get { dataSources[currentThing] }
    set { dataSources[currentThing] = newValue }
}
```

it all works.

In other words, the Way to do a "pointer or macro like thing", in this situation with a dictionary in Swift, is as above.

In fact, does that safely and correctly works in the intended way? To wit,

(A)

```
x = hugestuff.hot.enormousArray[13]
```

will ***not*** pointlessly copy the array during the process and

(B)

```
hugestuff.hot.searchRows = .. some new or modified array
```

will indeed ***"actually change"*** that array, i.e., it won't just instead incorrectly change some transient copy of the array somewhere.

##### To repeat, in (B),

```
hugestuff.hot.searchRows = hugestuff.hot.other.sortwhatever
```

Is hoping to be the same as

```
hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"].searchRows = 
   hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"].other.sortwhatever
```

In other words I am hoping that `hugestuff.hot.searchRows = ..` **in fact actually changes** `hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"]`

Is this perfectly correct?

I mention "current" Swift because, of course, Swift dramatically changed how arrays work at one point, and, Swift uses the ingenious *("But ask on SO before you try anything tricky")* copy-only-on-need approach for big arrays (or indeed any arrays).

---

BTW here is a fantastically useful answer to a related question [Is it absolutely the case that Swift >will not< deep copy a large array, when one "guard let" the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77969431/294884)

---

Coda, just for anyone browsing this, as well as the pure macro-like syntax sugar aspect ("it is much quicker to just type .hot"), a really useful thing is you can ..

```
var hot: .. {
    get { dataSources[currentThing] ?? some empty value }
```

If dataSources["sales"] say does not exist yet (for whatever reason: whether by design, eg, you are building them lazily, streaming, processing on other cores, whatever, or indeed just a plain programming mistake) you can handle all that in there.

Answer (score 1):

If `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays` is a class, `hot` will trivially act like a "pointer". After all, classes are *reference* types, and `hot` will return a reference.

From now on I will assume `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays` is a struct.

`Array` is copy-on-***write***. For the array storage to be copied, it has to

- be *written*, and
- it is shared by multiple `Array` variables (i.e. [`isKnownUniquelyReferenced`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/isknownuniquelyreferenced(_:)-98zpp) is false)

In both cases A and B, `hot`'s getter returns a copy of `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays`, but the arrays in the copies will share the same storage, because you are not writing to `hugestuff.hot.enormousArray`.

However, `hot` is not completely like a pointer. If you do:

```
hugeStuff.hot.enormousArray[someIndex] = something
```

`hot` returns a copy of `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays`, which shares the array storage with `dataSources[currentThing]`. Then you modified the `enormousArray` of the copy returned by `hot`. Now the array storage cannot be shared, so the whole array storage will be copied.

You can think of this as:

```
let temp = hugeStuff.hot
temp.enormousArray[someIndex] = something
hugeStuff.hot = temp
```

The array storage is not uniquely referenced here - `temp` and `huge.dataSources[someIndex]` share the storage.

A good way to determine whether array storages are copied is to use the "Allocations" tool in Instruments. Try it with this code:

```
struct ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays {
    var enormousArray = Array(repeating: 1, count: 1000)
    var searchRows = ["Row1", "Row2", "Row3"]
}

class HugeStuff {
    var dataSources = ["Foo": ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays()]
    var currentThing = "Foo"
    
    var hot: ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays {
        get { dataSources[currentThing]! }
        set { dataSources[currentThing] = newValue }
    }
}

let hugeStuff = HugeStuff()
// run each of these loops separately:

// case A
//for i in 0..<1000 {
//    let x = hugeStuff.hot.enormousArray[i]
//    print(x)
//}

// case B
//for i in 0..<1000 {
//    hugeStuff.hot.searchRows = ["Row \(i)"]
//    print("x")
//}

// case C
//for i in 0..<1000 {
//    hugeStuff.hot.enormousArray[i] = i
//    print("x")
//}
```

You can filter by "array", and you will see something like this in Instruments for case C:

[image]

The name `_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageSi_` is the mangled name for `ContiguousArrayStorage<Int>`. You can demangle these using the `swift demangle` command.

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering, YES `ThingWithIncrediblyLargeArrays` is a struct.  (The vars in the struct would be three or four (enormous) arrays.  I have edited the question to have more info.  I am investigating your amazing answer now thanks. `@inlinable` seems like amazing aspect.

Comment: Perhaps the key difficulty in my question is where it says ***"Is hoping to be the same as...."***

Comment: to wit, "In other words I am hoping that `hugestuff.hot.searchRows = ..` **in fact actually changes** `hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"]` "

Comment: @Fattie Actually `@inlinable` was just something I tried to see if it makes a difference, and it didn't. I didn't mean to put it in the answer :) `hugestuff.hot.searchRows = ..` *does* change `hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"]`, does it not? Your setter is what enabled you to do that. It doesn't change `hugestuff.dataSources["electrons"].enornousArray`, so the array storage is not copied.

Comment: @Fattie What you are hoping is true. What actually is your question?

Comment: Unreal!  :)   TY.  Yes, as it leads in the question "Is it perfectly true that ..."  It sounds like the answer, thank God, is a big Yes.