# Swift async externally fulfilled Task / Future like type

Tags: swift, async-await

I have a legacy API function that will provide a `UIViewController`. It takes as an argument a completion function. The view controller will call the completion function once after being presented with a result value.

```swift
func makeController(completion: @escaping (ViewResult) -> Void) -> UIViewController
```

I would like to wrap this in a slightly nicer API for async so that it becomes something like this:

```swift
func makeController() -> (UIViewController, FutureIsh<ViewResult>)
```

Where the `FutureIsh`, would have a caller facing interface similar to `Task` so that you can `await futureish.value`.

I'm wondering if there is an existing suitable type `FutureIsh`? I don't think I can use `Task` because its work block has to be given to it. I think I can make something with an `actor`, but if there's an existing type I'd prefer to use it.

---

Attempting to write this with `Task`, perhaps I could do…

```swift
func makeController() -> (UIViewController, Task<ControllerResult>) {
  // This doesn't exist, and I can't see it is possible to create
  // it with `withCheckedContinuation`.
  let task = Task<ControllerResult, Never>.taskWithAPromise()

  // Use the legacy API…
  let controller = makeController(completion: task.promise)

  return (controller, task)
}
```

Comment: I’ve scratched my head but I’ve not been able to construct the target API using a continuation. I need to get the continuation out so I can return the viewcontroller, I think.

Comment:  I’ll add some code in a bit.

Comment: There is a simple solution using Combine where your "FutureIsh" would become a Publisher (or a Combine Future). In order to know when the result is available, you need a subscriber. The second alternative is  Swift Concurrency: here, you are looking for `CheckedContinuation` respectively `UnsafeContinuation`. The Swift Concurrency solution is a bit more involved and requires a reference for the continuation and thus some "Object" where you hold that reference. You can also pass a Task as your FutureIsh, possibly being the simplest solution.

Comment: Watch “Meet async/await”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an `AsyncStream` that only produces one elemen.

[`AsyncStream.Continuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream/continuation) is allowed to escape. You can use [`makeStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream/makestream(of:bufferingpolicy:)) to get an "escaped" continuation and an `AsyncStream`.

Assuming `ViewResult` is `Sendable`, you can do

```
func makeController(completion: @escaping (ViewResult) -> Void) -> UIViewController {
    ...
}

func makeController() -> (UIViewController, Task<ViewResult, Never>) {
    let (stream, continuation) = AsyncStream.makeStream(of: ViewResult.self)
    
    // Here we wrap the AsyncStream into a Task
    // you can also just return the AsyncStream directly and let the caller consume it,
    // or Task.detached depending on what you need
    let task = Task {
       var iterator = stream.makeAsyncIterator()
        return await iterator.next()!
    }
    return (makeController {
        continuation.yield($0)
        continuation.finish()
    }, task)
}
```

Usage:

```
let (vc, task) = makeController()
print(vc)
print(await task.value)
```

Comment: Right!  … that is exactly what I am after :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification, and as an addition to the other answers, there's an alternative solution:

A mock for your API:

```
    @MainActor
    func makeController(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> UIViewController {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion("Finished")
        }
        return UIViewController()
    }
```

A Unit Test which runs the solution:

```
    @MainActor
    func testExample() async throws {
        
        @MainActor
        func makeController2() -> (UIViewController, Task<String, Never>) {
            // note: the continuation will be captured in escaping
            // closures, and  thus allocated on the heap:
            var cont: CheckedContinuation<String, Never>? = nil

            let viewController: UIViewController = makeController { string in
                guard let cont = cont else {
                    return
                }
                cont.resume(returning: string)
            }

            let task = Task { @MainActor in
                return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                    cont = continuation
                }
            }
            
            return (viewController, task)
        }

        let (a, b) = makeController2()
        print(Date(), a)
        let result = await b.value
        print(Date(), result)
    }
```

Note: you can use `CheckedContinuation` this way.

Comment: Hey – thanks for the answer. The use of `CheckedContinuation` like this is really interesting and I hadn't expected it to be legal! Do you happen to have a link to some kind of documentation that this is explicitly permitted? But I like this. Having a specific type to describe a closure that should only be called once, and is also escaped beyond the confines of `withCheckedContinuation` seems very useful.

Comment: @Benjohn Thanks for your reply. Beyond the official documentation, you can find more about its "history" in the Swift Forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/concurrency-continuations-for-interfacing-async-tasks-with-synchronous-code/43619. Note, that `CheckedContinuation` has a sister `UnsafeContinuation`. It's about _how_ the compiler handles violations of the contract using these values – the semantic is the same. If you have a question about capturing a value type in an escaping closure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024264/how-exactly-are-structs-captured-in-escaping-closures

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is to utilise `Task`:

```
func foo() -> (String, Task<String, Error>) {
    
    let task = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        return "Finished"
    }
    
    return ("Start", task)
}

let (a, b) = foo()
print(Date(), a)
let result = try await b.value
print(Date(), result)
```

The best way to test this code is in a Unit Test (i.e. not Playgrounds):

```
func testExample() async throws {
   ...
}
```

Console:

```
2024-01-18 12:24:26 +0000 Start
2024-01-18 12:24:27 +0000 Finished
```

Note that there are various ways, how you can implement the body of the outer task. You might have an object, say a UIViewController which has an "async property":

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var result: String {
        get async throws {
            ... // async code
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, you can await the value of the property:

```
    let task = Task {
        try await self.myViewController.result
    }
```

Again, there are various ways how to complete the property, either with Swift Concurrency, completion handlers or Combine.

Comment: Hi – I don't think this helps, I think I needed to be clearer in my question, sorry! I need to get the first result (in my case a view controller, in your example a string) from an existing API that takes a callback that will provide the result the task complets with.

Comment: @Benjohn Yep, please provide more context. In principle, this solution works. It's just the surrounding code that depends on your requirements, and determines how you need to "map" from different async technologies.