# iOS - Type 'DispatchQueue' has no member 'GlobalAttributes'

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have the following error:

> Type 'DispatchQueue' has no member 'GlobalAttributes'

In my code. Do you know why?

```
 public typealias Classification = (Label: DigitLabel, Confidence: CGFloat, BestPrototypeIndex: Int)
    public func classifyDigit(digit: DigitStrokes, votesCounted: Int = 5, scoreCutoff: CGFloat = 0.8) -> Classification? {
        if let normalizedDigit = normalizeDigit(inputDigit: digit) {
            let serviceGroup = DispatchGroup()
            let queue = ***DispatchQueue.global(attributes: DispatchQueue.GlobalAttributes.qosUserInitiated)***
            let serialResultsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "collect_results")

            var bestMatches = SortedMinArray<CGFloat, (DigitLabel, Int)>(capacity: votesCounted)
            for (label, prototypes) in self.normalizedPrototypeLibrary {

                queue.async(group: serviceGroup) {
                    var localBestMatches = SortedMinArray<CGFloat, (DigitLabel, Int)>(capacity: votesCounted)
                    var index = 0
                    for prototype in prototypes {
                        if prototype.count == digit.count {
                            let score = self.classificationScore(sample: normalizedDigit, prototype: prototype)
                            //if score < scoreCutoff {
                            localBestMatches.add(value: score, element: (label, index))
                            //}
                        }
                        index += 1
                    }
                    serialResultsQueue.async(group: serviceGroup) {
                        for (score, bestMatch) in localBestMatches {
                            bestMatches.add(value: score, element: bestMatch)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also attached [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3o6vgLnTV5RMmNyTkVqV0pvdkk/view?usp=sharing), just in case.

Comment: let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue), the message is correct.

Maybe you want to use `DispatchQueue.Attributes`?

**EDIT:**

I just had a closer look at the documentation:

`DispatchQueue.global()` seems to be changed. The documentation shows this declaration:

```
class func global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass = default) -> DispatchQueue
```

I tested some variations, Xcode proposed and found this line:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated)
```

> I did not test, if this works 100% with your example, but Xcode will compile it

Comment: Now it is "Type 'DispatchQueue.Attributes' has no member 'qosUserInitiated'".

Comment: I read a bit in the documentation and let Xcode show me some classes I could put in `global()` and found something that will at least compile. Lokk at my edit

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you. :)

Comment: oh no now it shows "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" :(
(I can post the whole log if you need) 
http://pastebin.com/kSi3n5HX

Comment: :-( This can have multiple reasons. Try cleaning the project and restarting Xcode. If it still doesn't work, google for "ios segmentation fault 11". There are tons of different answers about it. Maybe one of them works for you

Comment: I've tried different solutions and none of them worked. Could you look into the problem for me? It would be very nice of you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(DispatchQueue.main) {
                                                    self.mapView.add(self.mapPolyline)
                                                } in Swift 3.0 i've tried with
DispatchQueue.global().asynchronously(DispatchQueue.main) {
                                                    self.mapView.add(self.mapPolyline)
                                                }                                                                      but both shows the same error as "value of type dispathQuoue has no member asynchronously"