# Swift 2 to 3 Migration dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, ios10, dispatch-async

I have the following code that I've been trying to translate into swift 3 from swift 2.  Here is what I have so far.

```
DispatchQueue.async(group: DispatchQueue.global(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),execute: {
            self.controllerDelegate?.codeToRun(progressWindowViewController: self)
        })
```

I am getting an error that says Cannot invoke 'global' with an argument list of type (int,int).  I know that the global queue needs this though unless they changed it in swift 3? **What is the correct way to do global queues in Swift 3?**

Previous Swift 2 Equivlent

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),{
            self.controllerDelegate?.codeToRun(self)
        })
```

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this it will work.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    }
})
```

If you still need any help feel free to ask here.

Comment: Thanks so much exactly what I was looking for.  I guess they made some kind of new qos: class thing now to describe the different types of threads.

Comment: always Welcome dude..

Comment: my previous code started with async from the main thread hope that will not be issue.  I'll have to play around with it.  Will this code work in reverse also? Like starting with DispatchQueue.main.async?

Comment: Yep. It will work both way..

Comment: thanks you save my time...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a closer and simpler approach to your question would be:

`DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { ... }`

Comment: Out of curiosity what makes this answer faster, might change which answer is accepted

Comment: @JosephAstrahan it's not faster, but definitely closer to what you were proposing, having a single completion block instead of 2. Anyway, the chosen answer is correct as well.