# How to cancel a specific DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter event?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

The question was already asked some time ago. But I'm not able to find a nice solution matching to the current Swift version.

- [Cancel a timed event in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359768/cancel-a-timed-event-in-swift) (is already outdated)
- [How to cancel DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) in Swift3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848550/how-to-cancel-dispatchqueue-main-asyncafterdeadline-time-in-swift3?noredirect=1&lq=1) (got no simple & right answer)

---

Swift 4 - How to cancel a specific call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`?

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    // my code
}
```

---

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    // just cancel this event!
}
```

Comment: do you check this answer at `Cancel a timed event in Swift?`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684520/2463616