# Cannot invoke 'global' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'

Tags: migration, swift3

I am on the process of migrating old swift code to Swift 3.0, and at times via Swift 2.3.
On the way I made some wrong actions, leading to a mix up of different versions here and there.
That said I must now fall back on my feet and make things work.

Here some code I have:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(Int(qualityOfServiceClass.rawValue), 0)
backgroundQueue.asynchronously(execute: {
    self.getAppData()
    self.waitingForAppData = false
    self.busyWithAppDataAccess = false
})
```

And here is an error message I get, relative to the code above:

```
Cannot invoke 'global' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: What's the 0 in your call supposed to be for? What function are you looking for? https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue

Comment: Perhaps this? https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global

Comment: This is code which was working in Swift version 2.3, I now get an error.

Comment: Grand Central Dispatched has been massively overhauled and improved in Swift 3. Running your code through the code migrator should pick up most of the differences, and apply the changes necessary for you.

Comment: Well, then why am I left with this error? Is it possible that part of the code has not been migrated?

Comment: Well, have you run the migrator?

Comment: By the way the the code migrator can also migrate from 2.3 to 3.0; not only from old Swift to 2.3 or to 3.0. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130568/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-michel).

Comment: Yes I have  run the migrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 to 3 Migration dispatch\_get\_global\_queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744291/swift-2-to-3-migration-dispatch-get-global-queue)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find a matching signature for your use of the `global` method. I'm assuming that the second `Int` is suppose to represent the relative priority.

Since `global(priority:)` has been deprecated. Here is how you could update your code for Swift 3:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
backgroundQueue.async {
    self.getAppData()
    self.waitingForAppData = false
    self.busyWithAppDataAccess = false
}
```

You could also do this to keep relative priority in the picture. However, it doesn't seem to be relevant anymore when using Swift 3.

```
let qos = DispatchQoS(qosClass: .background, relativePriority: 0)
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qos.qosClass)
backgroundQueue.async {
    self.getAppData()
    self.waitingForAppData = false
    self.busyWithAppDataAccess = false
}
```