# "modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread" (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3

I have the following code. It worked fine in Swift 2.3:

```
 self.newsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.newsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(topics.count), height: self.newsScrollView.frame.size.height)
    for i in 0..<topics.count {
        let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * self.newsScrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: self.newsScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.newsScrollView.frame.size.height)
        let topic = topics[i]
        let newsView = TrendingTopicView(topic: topic, frame: frame)
        newsView.delegate = self
        self.newsScrollView.addSubview(newsView)
    }
```

Now, I receive a warning in the debugger:

```
  This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after 
  the engine was accessed from the main thread.
  This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
```

So, I tried editing it to this:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.newsScrollView.addSubview(newsView)  
 }
```

But I still receive the warning. I have also tried the DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:) as well. What am I doing wrong? If I'm not mistaken, the DispatchQueue.main.async inSwift 3 is the equivalent of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) in Swift 2.x right?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're looking too narrowly.  The code you've posted doesn't show anything running on a background thread but if that's where you're crashing then it is definitely being called by something that is.  Find all places where you hop on a background thread and make sure nothing down the call chain modifies the UI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in })

Comment: i've tried that as well @sanju ju

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28321213/6521116