# dispatch_get_main_queue() objc warning after Swift 3 conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I Convert my Objective C + Swift 2.x code to Swift 3 in Xcode 8. After converting the code i am getting these new warning that i don't know if it's safe ti ignore/how to resolve it.

**My Swift 3 code :**

```
func getUserNotificationFromServer(_ completionQueue:DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main,callback: @escaping (_ succeeded: Bool, _ response: AnyObject?) -> Void)  {
```

**Objective C code that calls this function**

```
 [wsManager getUserFavouritesFromServer:dispatch_get_main_queue() callback:^(BOOL succeeded, id  _Nullable response) {
```

Warning that i am receiving

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'dispatch_queue_t _Nonnull' (aka
>   'NSObject *') to parameter of type
>   'OS_dispatch_queue * _Nonnull'

Any thoughts ?

Comment: check this post, here is described perfectly: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3)

Comment: That post talks about Swift code, this warning comes when i call method written in Swift 3 from my Objective C class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why, but the `DispatchQueue` is exposed as `OS_dispatch_queue *` in the generated {ProjectModuleName}-Swift.h .

(Better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.)

As far as I tested, just casting as suggested in the message suppresses the warning, and the code works as expected:

```
[wsManager getUserNotificationFromServer:(OS_dispatch_queue * _Nonnull)dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                callback:^(BOOL succeeded, id  _Nullable response) {
```