# iOS DIsptchqueue.global Error

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes:DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async { () -> Void
```

I get the error at attributes. It says

> (Argument labels(attributes:) does not match any available overloads)

Answer (score 1):

That means your implementation is wrong. For Confirmation Press & Hold `cmd` and click to Get documentation for correct code.

Reference:

[How to create dispatch queue in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3)