# priority and background was deprecated in ios 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios8

I have an app that is developed with old swift code. now I'm updating it to latest swift syntax. While updating I found difficult in dispatch queue, here it's giving two warnings as global(priority) was deprecated in ios 8 and background was deprecated in ios 8.

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.background).async(execute: { [weak self] in     //Getting warning in this line
    if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.populateOutBoundContacts()
        strongSelf.lookForContactsToPresent()
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806522/5362750 look this

Answer (score 9):

The syntax was changed to `DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass)`. You don't need to call `async(execute)`, you can directly call `async` and write the code to be executed in the closure.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{ [weak self] in    
    if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.populateOutBoundContacts()
        strongSelf.lookForContactsToPresent()
    }        
}
```

When updating old code, I strongly suggest going through the documentation of the respective classes and using Xcode's auto completion, it can save you a lot of time when looking for the new syntax/methods.