# DispatchGroup.wait not waiting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having an issue understanding or using Dispatchgroup. I've read a lot about them however most examples / documentation are very vague or doesn't resemble what I want to do, however every time I mention my problem everyone says "USE DISPATCH GROUPS!".

Here's what I want to do(NOTE: SEQUENTIAL ORDER IS CRUCIAL):

- Send Bluetooth Write characteristic.
- *device receives value, and spits something in response*
- Read Bluetooth response (via a read characteristic)
- Send a new write characteristic (a different command)
- *device receives NEW command, spits NEW data response*

Repeat twice (3 commands total, 3 different responses total).

---

My code:

```
func tPodInitialSetUp()
    {
        print ("* * * * * BEGIN SET-UP * * * * *")
        let setupDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        self.writeValue(command: Data(CommandModeCmd)) //231: Put t-Pod in command mode, burst mode is OFF returns OK
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.wait()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        deviceConnected?.readValue(for: deviceConnectedCh1n2Char!)
        print("Sent command 231: returned: \(receivedString1)")
        if receivedString1.lowercased() == "ok"
        {
            print("t-Pod burst mode is OFF")
        }
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.wait()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        self.writeValue(command: Data(loadProbeCalCmd)) //202: load calibration constants of probe, returns ok or 0
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.wait()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        deviceConnected?.readValue(for: deviceConnectedCh1n2Char!)
        print("Sent command 202: returned: \(receivedString1)")
        if receivedString1.lowercased() == "ok"
        {
            print("Probe Constants loaded")
        }
        if receivedString1 == "0"
        {
            print("No probe connected")
        }
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.wait()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        self.writeValue(command: Data(probeSNCmd)) //205: load probe serial number
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.wait()

        setupDispatchGroup.enter()
        deviceConnected?.readValue(for: deviceConnectedCh1n2Char!)
        print("Sent command 205: returned: \(receivedString1)")
        if (receivedString1.count == 6)
        {
            print("received Probe SN: \(receivedString1)")
            probeSN = receivedString1
        }
        setupDispatchGroup.leave()

        setupDispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main)
        {
            tPodSN = String(describing: connectedDeviceName!.dropFirst(7))
            print ("* * * SET-UP COMPLETE * * *")
            self.writeValue(command: Data(resetCmd)) //200: resets t-Pod
            self.writeValue(command: Data(beaconOffCmd)) //211: turns beacon off (temperature output)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5)
        {
            self.dataDisplaySubView.isHidden = false
            print ("Adding observers!")

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateIncomingData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: DATA_PARSED), object: nil) //Run every time you receive data from BLE

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.calculateTNU), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: TOGGLESWITCH_TOGGLED), object: nil) //Run in case the toggle switches change and data needs to be re-calculated

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.parseReceivedData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: DEVICE_FINISHED_SENT_DATA), object: nil) //Run every time you receive the notification that the whole data has been sent
        }
    }
```

This calls the bluetooth write command which has the following code and confirmation:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error writing descriptor: " + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        print("Descriptor Value sent")
    }
```

Now, Here's my output:

```
* * * * * BEGIN SET-UP * * * * *
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
Sent command 231: returned: **T-Pod-9Ch**
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
Sent command 202: returned: **T-Pod-9Ch**
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
Sent command 205: returned: **T-Pod-9Ch**
* * * SET-UP COMPLETE * * *
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
***** WRITING *****
Wrote: 1 bytes
Characteristic Value sent
Adding observers!
Characteristic Value sent
Characteristic Value sent
Characteristic Value sent
Characteristic Value sent
Clearing TNU Array
```

Now, as you can see "Characteristic Value Sent" is the confirmation the bluetooth function gives when it sends the value, however this output is created AFTER it finished running the entire code, so basically it put the commands in some pipeline, forgot about them did everything else and THEN sent the commands and therefore the response I'm reading are all nonsense! As you can see all received strings are **T-Pod-9Ch** (which is just its normal burst output), the expected responses I should get from the commands are OK, OK and a 6 digit number (in that order).
Please help, I've read so many times about how dispatch groups are supposed to work but I just can't get them to do what I want.

Comment: You're entering, leaving, and waiting the group all on a single thread. That's completely pointless. Every single time you call `wait()` the group's counter is at `0` because you already left the group.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I don't really understand how its supposed to be formatted then, from what I understood each individual task had to be inside enter/leave commands and I need them to wait for it to finish each individual command

Comment: Dispatch queues are for synchronizing things between threads. Generally you use them like this: 1) call `enter()` on the current thread, 2) start some asynchronous task and/or run some code on another thread or dispatch queue, 3) have the async task call `leave()` when it's done, 4) repeat for any other tasks that need to be done, and 5) use `notify()` to make some code run when all the `enter()` calls have been balanced by `leave()` calls.

Comment: So (and forgive the lack of line breaks, which can't be put into comments): `group.enter(); someQueue.async { Foo(); group.leave() }; group.notify(someQueue) { Bar() }`. In this example, `Bar()` will not be called until after `Foo()` has finished.

Comment: When you have a bunch of parallel tasks and you need to do some completion task when they're all done, dispatch groups are a godsend. If there's just one task, you could of course just call the completion from the async task's completion handler, but groups can still be kinda nice to cut down on the "pyramid of doom" that you can get from a whole bunch of nested code blocks.

Comment: but I do not want to run them in parallel, I want them to be in sequence, I want task B to ONLY be executed AFTER task A has been complete, not at the same time. So from what I understand you said I should then have multiple groups? or nested groups? group.enter(); myQueue.async{Task A}; group.leave(); group.notify(myQueue { TaskB};. But then Task B needs its own group and its own queue? so group2 mySecondQueue etc? and a third one would be a third group third queue? this starts to sound like  pyramid of doom thing

Answer (score 9):

If I got your question right, you need to wait for an answer before sending new command.

But your writes doesn't have a completion block, that's why in your case using dispatchGroup makes no sense.

The code below is a common example to use dispatch groups

```
func someMethod(completionHandler: @escaping ()-> Void) {


 //we need to get or set some data in separated queue
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    //let's say we have an array of urls and we need to load images and put them to an array
    for url in someUrlArray {
          group.enter()
          SomeLoaderClass.load(url) { image in
                //add received image

                //leave the group
               group.leave() 
           }
    }

    //now we need to wait until all images will be downloaded 
    group.wait()

    //then we can finish and call the completion in the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         completionHandler()
    }
   }
}
```

In your situation you may have several options:

First, if you know that if you send one command and receive an answer exactly for that command, you can call methods in order below:

1. Call one method to Send command 1
2. Call another method after an answer for command 1 will be received
3. Call yet another method to Send command 2
4. And one more method after getting an answer for command 2
   ...

n. Finish setup

Like if I need to register a user, I need to send defined credentials first, get token from the server, then run something after it.

So you will have to add an additional method for each command and you will call them according the order

If you can't recognize for which command you're going to get an answer and you sure that you've send only one command and waiting only one answer, then you can use dispatch group in the way described below:

```
typealias Callback = ()->Void
class SomeManagerClass {
       var callback: Callback?

       func initiateSetup(){
              DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
                    let group = DispatchGroup()
                   //now we can send commands
                   group.enter()
                   self?.sendCommand(SomeDataForTheFirstCommand) {
                          //when the first answer will be received, it will init the callback, so you can leave the group now
                         group.leave()
                    }
                   //sending the second command
                    group.enter()
                   self?.sendCommand(SomeDataForTheSecondCommand) {
                          //waiting for the second answer will be received
                         group.leave()
                    }

                    //.... more commands sending same way
                    group.wait()
                    //now all commands was send and you got an answer for each

                    //finishing setup 
                         DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self?.finishSetup()
                   }
              }
       }

      func sendCommand(_ command: Data, callback: Callback?){
             self.writeValue(command: command)
             self.callback = callback 
      }

      func answerReceived(){
             //this is just an example method that is called when you get an answer for any command
            //now we can callback 
            self.callback?()
      }

      func finishSetup(){

           //do something 
      }
}
```

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: I will try to use this, it seems to do what I want. I just have a quick question, how does the program know what the callback is? like say I have a method that calls that peripheral  didwritevaluefor (see my original code). How does the program know that it has to wait until it receives "confirmation" (or that print statement I have). I was thinking if I put a notification there or something. . .just so that I can make sure to wait until it writes it before proceeding

Comment: @dvd.Void callback is just a function that doesn't have any parameters and doesn't return any objects. You just call it to leave the dispatch group and start the next method calling. If no one will call the method answerReceived(), the app will not leave the group and setup process won't be finished. Each sendCommand call will change stored callback to leave the group after exact command. You can use notifications, delegates or whatever. You should just call answerReceived() after each command was sent at the time you are sure that that command was proceeded.

Comment: @dvd.Void Oh, wait, in your case it seems that you have to store all blocks...I'm not sure but if you are getting a command write result asynchronously, so it may change stored callback by the second function, before the first one use that callback. We need to test it and check console output same way you've show in your question. If callbacks will have broken order, then we will have to use DispatchWorkItem for each command to store them in the array of blocks, or use DispatchSemaphore. But anyway, let me know how it will work in your code. We also may have a chat later to make code work.

Comment: Since you just call the completion handler on a dispatch queue anyway, `group.notify()` is better than `group.wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using Dispatch group

```
private func performTask1() -> String {
    print("Task1")
    var result: String?
    let background = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    background.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        result = "Task1 is performed"
         dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
   dispatchGroup.wait()
    return result!
}
```

Try this out to understand concept of DispactGroup!

Comment: In this example isn't your dispatchGroup.wait() being executed on the main thread? main thread will be blocked and wait till group items leave.

Answer (score 1):

**Try! this**

Required **DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)** for **leave()**

```
func dispatchGroup() -> String {

   var message = ""

   let group = DispatchGroup()

   group.enter()

   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        message = "Hiii Friends"
        group.leave()
   }

   group.wait()

   return message
}
```