# moya request in background thread

Tags: swift, moya, reactive-swift

I'm wondering how to make a request in a background thread, what I mean by that is the fetching in a background thread and then come back to the main thread

Currently I can go the main thread after the request by calling:

`.observe(on: UIScheduler())`

But I didn't succeeded to make the request in another thread, you think it's a good idea to make it in another thread ?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for instead of the observe(on:) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806522/3393964

Comment: Thanks I can use it, do you a Reactive way to use it ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you were using React, I don't know.

Comment: I use swift but react programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `SignalProducer`, you can use the [`start(on:)` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/4.0.0/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L1981) so that it's `start()` method is run on a different scheduler. So you could do `producer.start(on: QueueScheduler())` to ensure it is started asynchronously on a GCD queue.