# Run a background thread on Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I have a function that goes like this:

```
fileprivate func setupImageViewWithURL(url: URL) {
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    do {
        try image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))!
    } catch is NSError {
        print("Failed")
    }

    image = self.imageWithImage(sourceImage: image!, scaledToWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
    self.imageImageView.image = image
    self.imageImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: (image?.size.height)!)
}
```

I want to run it on a `Background` `thread`.

I've tried the `GDC` methods of `Swift2`, but it didn't work.

Did anything change in the thread topic in `Swift3`?

Thank you!

Comment: http://swiftable.io/2016/06/dispatch-queues-swift-3/

Comment: @New16 I've already tried it, it doesn't even complies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dispatch_sync, dispatch_async, dispatch_after, etc in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801370/how-do-i-dispatch-sync-dispatch-async-dispatch-after-etc-in-swift-3).

Comment: @FS.O6 I am using it in my code. I don't know the way you are implementing it. Show what error you are getting.

Comment: You don't want to run it on background thread. UI updates should be never performed on background threads.

Comment: @MaxPevsner I want to load the image on the background because it's very slow now

Comment: @FS.O6, see my answer below.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's OK to load image on the background, but it's not OK to perform UI updates on background thread. That's why the function must contain two threads.

```
func setupImageViewWithURL(url: URL) {
    var image: UIImage? = nil

    DispatchQueue.global().async { 
        do {
            try image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))!
        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if image != nil {
                image = self.imageWithImage(sourceImage: image!, scaledToWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
                self.imageImageView.image = image
                self.imageImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: (image?.size.height)!)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `ImageWithImage` is a method that crops the image, can it be done on a background thread?

Comment: @FS.O6, I don't think it should be problem. You can test it.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.0

> ```
> func setupImageViewWithURL(url: URL) {
>
>     var image: UIImage? = nil
>     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
>         do {
>             try image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))!
>         } catch {
>             print("Failed")
>         }
>         DispatchQueue.main.async {
>             if image != nil {
>                 image = self.imageWithImage(sourceImage: image!, scaledToWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
>                 self.imageImageView.image = image
>                 self.imageImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: (image?.size.height)!)
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: What is this answer add to the already accepted answer? To me it's just a copy-paste with minimal change.

Answer (score 0):

> DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
>
> }