# Swift - Load ViewController in background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

i have a View Controller with a huge stack of Images in an Array. When i press the Button that takes me to View Controller it takes about 8-15 Seconds to load. Now I want to make a Loading screen so every time the app start, the View controller should be loaded in background.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you could try the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42189146/4056108)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do that, relating to the final user experience, is using an **Activity Indicator**.

You should add it normally to your ViewController and relating it to your swift viewController'file.

When the loading will start, you must start to "spin" your activity indicator: in this way the user "understand" that "something will be loaded in a while".

When the loading will be finished, you must just make it **hidden**.

Moreover, if you want to be sure that images will be added **after** the loading of the view controller itself, load them through the **viewWillAppear** method, NOT **viewDidLoad**!

Answer (score 2):

don't load image in ViewDidLoad()

use this  to load image

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you for background queue and main queue operation !!!!

```
func bgQueue(queueName: String, completion codeBlock: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            codeBlock(true)
        }
    }

func mainQueue(codeBlock: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            codeBlock(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Methods should start with lowercase letter in Swift.

Comment: by the way, why should methods start with a lowercase letter?

Comment: Guys its coding standard, not compulsory !!!! or it's not going to give you any kind of compile or run time error ...

Comment: Sure, Bhavesh, but coding standards are not there just to be there. They serve a purpose. If you ignore the standards your code looks funny (or even wrong) to everyone else. Don't isolate yourself. Follow the standards. :)