# Like as AsyncTask in android what is equivalent in iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift

I have just started learning iOS programming. Like as AsyncTask in android what is equivalent in iOS.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801370/how-do-i-dispatch-sync-dispatch-async-dispatch-after-etc-in-swift-3 hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact equivalent, but you have several possibilities to execute code in parallel: e. g. [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch), [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue), and other.

Comment: can't we execute code serially second one gets started only when first gets complete..

Comment: @user2273146 Yes you can, you can create a serial or a concurrent queue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there more than just one concurrency technique for working with iOS, but I suggest to read about the [GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch) world.

Working with [DispatchQueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) is very easy now (after releasing Swift 3), you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805885/how-to-create-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3) to know how you can simply create one.

Also, you might want to check [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue).

If you are interested, check [Choosing Between NSOperation and Grand Central Dispatch](https://cocoacasts.com/choosing-between-nsoperation-and-grand-central-dispatch/).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/quickest solution in Swift 3.0 is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // your code goes here
}
```

That executes your code on the main thread asynchronously.