# translate dispatch_async in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, dispatch-async

I am trying translate the objective c code bellow to swift, i did so far but i get some error.. any help appreciate.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.incomingCall animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in swift version i did in this way but i get an error :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // Show the alert
           self.window?.rootViewController?.present(self.iincomingCall(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Comment: What's the error? Which version of Swift? 2 or 3?

Comment: If you are using Swift 3 then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801370/how-do-i-dispatch-sync-dispatch-async-dispatch-after-etc-in-swift-3?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swift 3 syntax is

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //your code
 }
```

Comment: should be something like?  DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
            
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(self.iincomingCall(), animated: true, completion: nil)    
            
        })