# How to delay code from executing until collection view data is reloaded?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an application that has two collection views in one. I want to first populate the first collection view, and then the second. First, I set the delegate of `photoCollectionView` to `self`. Then, I populated the collectionview by calling `photoCollectionView.reloadData()`. However, I want `photoCollectionView.reloadData()` to first complete before any further code is executed because when I included the code underneath it, the collection view I was initially trying to populate doesn't populate. However, when I remove the code, it does populate. I tried to use DispatchQueue, but I had no luck.

```
photoCollectionView.dataSource = self
photoCollectionView.reloadData() // I want this code to complete before executing anything else under it.

media.removeAll()

let assetVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video , options: nil)
assetVideo.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
    self.media.append(object)
})

self.media.reverse()

videoControllerView.dataSource = self
videoControllerView.reloadData()
```

Code after adding DispatchQueue. When executing this code, the collection view does not populate. However, if we comment out all the code in the DispatchQueue, it populates.

```
photoCollectionView.dataSource = self
photoCollectionView.reloadData()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.media.removeAll()

    let assetVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video , options: nil)
    assetVideo.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
        self.media.append(object)
    })

    self.media.reverse()

    self.videoControllerView.dataSource = self
    self.videoControllerView.reloadData()
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use dispatch async method.

Comment: @RealmOfFire I used `DispatchQueue.main.async` as shown in my post above, do you mean something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801371/9137841 refer this

Comment: @RealmOfFire Whats the difference between using the method you specified and `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: sorry i dont know because i am new in swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reloadData` unfortunately does not have a completion handler, but it's relatively easy to achieve the same effect by putting the call into a `CATransaction` block.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    // this runs after reloadData is done
}
photoCollectionView.reloadData()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Do you mean `photoCollectionView.reloadData()` instead of `self.media.removeAll()`? Also, `CATransaction.setCompletionHandler` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `photoCollectionView.reloadData() ` (whatever the first reloadData is you want to wait for) and `setCompletionBlock`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Okay so just to clarify, the code within `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock` runs after `photoCollectionView.reloadData()` is complete?

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata (last answer) for a nice example of how this can be made into an extension.